# how to increase /usr size?

Tags: linux, partitioning

```
rootfs                                                  323M  217M   90M   71% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M    0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   1.6G  704K  1.6G    1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ae86b7e0-cec7-4981-ae40-9b6763919ab0  323M  217M   90M   71% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M    0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   6.9G  768K  6.9G    1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb9                                               191G   68G  113G   38% /home
/dev/sdb8                                               368M   11M  339M    3% /tmp
/dev/sdb5                                               8.3G  8.2G     0  100% /usr
/dev/sdb6                                               2.8G  1.8G  885M   67% /var
```

how terrible my /dev/sdb5 is full,how can increase the size of /usr and do not damage my system?

Comment: See [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Is /usr/ on a different file system, because to only make it bigger it will need to be, copy the contents to a different fs, and set up fstab to autmount it.

Comment: What is on sdb1..4, can you move parts from /usr over there and symlink it back? (Not /usr/lib and such, maybe /usr/src). New disks become cheaper every day, 6 months ago I paid € 50 for a 500 GB SATA-II.

Answer (score 1):

You can only resize disks when they are unmounted and you cannot easily unmount the `/usr` partition while your system is running. So, download a copy of [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), burn it to CD and boot from it.

Once you have booted into the GParted system, you should be able to use Gnome's partitioner (`gparted`) to resize your partitions:

[image]

Resizing/editing partitions can be dangerous, I recommend you use a tool like [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make a [backup of your drive](http://www.howtoforge.com/back-up-restore-hard-drives-and-partitions-with-clonezilla-live) before doing anything.

Comment: That, and use LVM next time you install a new system where the final size of /usr and other partitions is not given.